# get minutes from .toISOString date

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, date, utc

I need to get the minutes passed from certain date(in rails server) to current date(in js).

Rails code:

```
return secTime = record.last_updated.to_i
```

Js code:

```
new Date(Number(secTime)*1000).toISOString()
=> "2014-02-09T12:21:31.000Z"
```

I would like to do like this:

```
new Date(Number(secTime)*1000).toISOString().getMinutes()
```

But it's not working...

Comment: In this case, "2014-02-09T12:21:31.000Z", you would want to extract the number 21?

Comment: I'm getting the date from rails server. See updated answer.

Comment: And why not just use the `.getMinutes()` method on the Date object itself, instead of converting to string?

Comment: Because I'm getting 21 min... The time was `12:21` So I have to get many minutes..

Comment: What are you expecting? 12*60+21 minutes from the start of the day?

Comment: minutes from `new Date(Number(secTime)*1000).toISOString()` to `new Date().toISOString()`  ("2014-02-09T17:34:38.909Z").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(new Date() - new Date(Number(secTime)*1000)) / (60*1000)
```

You can just subtract Date objects like numbers.

Answer (score 0):

```
function minutesPassed(d) {
   var minutes = (new Date() - d) / (1000*60);
   return minutes;
}

var certainDate = (new Date().getTime()) - 1000*60*20; // i.e, 20 minutes ago
alert(minutesPassed(certainDate) + " minutes passed") // "20 minutes passed"
```